# From angular version 11 to version 12, AgmMarkerSpiderModule does not work

Tags: angular, upgrade

Error: node_modules/agm-oms/marker-spider.module.d.ts:7:22 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but could
not be resolved to an NgModule class.

This likely means that the library (agm-oms/marker-spider.module) which declares AgmMarkerSpiderModule has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.

export declare class AgmMarkerSpiderModule {

tired to upgrade the library but no luck

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve this issue by running the below command

It will solve the noncompatible package not being able to run in ivy problem!

```
ngcc
```

You can also configure a `postinstall` script to run ngcc, if you do a fresh `npm install`

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "postinstall": "ngcc",
    ...
}
```

[NGCC – Angular Compatibility Compiler](https://frontegg.com/blog/mastering-angular-16-compatibility-uncovering-the-intricacies-of-view-engine-ivy-engine-and-beyond#:%7E:text=The%20Angular%20Compatibility%20Compiler%2C%20or,applications%20to%20integrate%20view%20SDKs.)

[ngcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62636918/what-are-the-reasons-for-adding-angular-postinstall-ngcc-script-in-the-proj)

Comment: how can i do this, i am new in angular, thank you

Comment: @MegiKuka in the terminal where you run `npm run start`, run `ngcc` then after that is done run `npm run start`

Comment: it does not recognise the command

Comment: @MegiKuka Could you try `npx ngcc` or run a fresh `npm install` after deleting node_modules and package.json